# ShouldRetryOn in DbExecutionStrategy not always works

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

Mostly it works but sometimes I receive error messages:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> ORA-03135: Connection lost contact
>
> ... in C:\xxx\Controllers\XController.cs:line 108

So line 108 is `return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);` Weird....

---

```
class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", () => new MyDbExecutionStrategy(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyDbExecutionStrategy : DbExecutionStrategy
{
    public MyDbExecutionStrategy(int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxDelay)
        : base(maxRetryCount, maxDelay)        {        }

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception ex)
    {
        return true; // for simplicity
    }
}
```

I had to do another wrapper and catch Oracle errors manually to overcome this. When I debug and simulate DB error the execution consistently goes into `ShouldRetryOn` method.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just reaching the `maxRetryCount`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the connection string in web.config by setting `Validate Connection = true`. Also try to check the `connection status  == Open` for connection received from the pool when you are doing the `Connection.Open()`

Also do check this [source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_03135_connection_lost_contact.htm) for the error you are getting

> Question:  I am attempting to connect to my Oracle database and I get
> the ORA-03135 error:
>
> ORA-03135: connection lost contact tips
>
> What can I do to avoid the ORA-03135 error?
>
> Answer:  The oerr utility shows this for the ORA-03135 error:
>
> ORA-03135: connection lost contact
>
> Cause:  1) Server unexpectedly terminated or was forced to terminate.
> or  2) Server timed out the connection.
>
> Action: 1) Check if the server session was terminated.
> 2) Check if the timeout parameters are set properly in
> sqlnet.ora.
>
> The ORA-03135 error is common when connecting remotely when a firewall
> terminates the connection.
>
> One solution for the ORA-03135 error is to increase the value of the
> sqlnet.ora expire_time parameter in the sqlnet.ora file or to check
> for a expire parameter in a SQL*Plus profile.
>
> To diagnose the ORA-03135 error, start by checking to see if the OS
> PID still exists, using the ps â€“ef|grep syntax.
>
> Check to see if there is a Network Address Translation (NAT) between
> the client and server
>
> In Windows, check to see if a Windows firewall is checking for your
> local connections:
>
> Windows XP -> Control panel -> security -> Tab "Advanced"
>
> Also, setting the parameters sqlnet.inbound_connect_timeout and
> inbound_connect_timeout_listenername to 0 can stop the ORA-03135
> error.